# How to correctly change the value between v-tab-item tags?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to grab data in `v-tab-item` tags. What's happening is that when I change between them the values are always the same.

I'm using `:value` in `v-tab-item` which references the `href`of `v-tab` as shown in the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs#tab), but still doesn't work.

I've created a [sample](https://codepen.io/pmpc94/pen/wbZEWo) in codepen to show what's happening right now.

Comment: Because the inputs is global for all tabs. You have to separate it in order to get different values for each tab.

Comment: **1)** You're overriding `index` in your nested loops. Don't! Use a different var name for one of them (`key`, perhaps!?). **2)** You're (re)using the same `inputs` array in all tabs. If you want them different, have one for each.